# Конкатенация в макросах - не срабатывает

Tags: c++

Код не работает так, как я хочу.

```
#include <iostream>

#define fPRINT(x) f ## x ## Print

enum Num { One=1, Two, Three };

void fOnePrint(Num n)
{
    std::cout << "Name:" << __FUNCTION__;
}

void fTwoPrint(Num n)
{
    std::cout << "Name:" << __FUNCTION__;
}

int main()
{
    fPRINT(One);

    return 0;
}
```

Автор книги пишет, что макрос должен сделать подстановку, но при вызове ничего не происходит (как-будто fOnePrint не вызывается). Ошибок компиляции и ворнингов нету, код успешно отрабатывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы работало ожидаемым образом, надо написать например так:

```
fPRINT(One)(One);
```

Первый `One` попадает в макрос и т.о. формируется имя функции `fOnePrint`. Но чтобы вызвать эту функцию нужно передать нужные параметры. В частности, добавить ещё `(One)`.

Вообще, у компиляторов есть ключи, позволяющие увидеть код после работы препроцессора. Это позволит Вам увидеть во что разворачивается макрос на самом деле.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо! Понятно и доступно!!

Answer (score 0):

Вы забываете вызывать функцию. Макрос `fPRINT( Two )` возвращает указатель на функцию `void (*)(Num)` следовательно надо вызвать и передать что-то туда.

---

```
#include <iostream>

#define fPRINT(x) f##x##Print

enum Num
{
    One = 1, Two, Three
};

void fOnePrint( Num n )
{
    std::cout << "Name:" << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

void fTwoPrint( Num n )
{
    std::cout << "Name:" << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   auto p =  fPRINT( Two );
   (*p)(Three);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: мне кажется говорить что _Макрос fPRINT( Two ) возвращает_ не совсем верно

Comment: @Grundy тоже верно - думаю ожидаемее было написать "в результате макро-подстановки препроцессора на место define fPRINT окажется имя функции, которая имеет свою сигнатуру, а именно ..."

Comment: да, так лучше :-) и еще можно сам результат после подстановки макросов привести, чтобы все вопросы остальные отбросить

Comment: @rikimaru2013, спасибо вам! К сожалению, пока ставить плюсы на ответы не позволяет рейтинг =(

Comment: @Robert книга вещь хорошая, но на практике не применяйте такое - вон лучше запишите себе фразу "std::function" и почитайте про неё через пару месяцев. Там вообще мощь)